# How to properly close connection to MQ Manager?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I made an Java app to connect to an MQ Queue and send a message. It uses a timer to invoke the function many times, so when there's a message recorded in another queue, gets it and sends it to the other.

```
            mensajeHost = dataqueue.read(Constantes.CRITERIO_LECTURA_DQ,Constantes.DQGET_TIEMPO_MAXIMO, "GE");

            if (mensajeHost != null) {

                comando = mensajeHost.getString();

                key = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_KEY_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_KEY_ENT_EE);

                qmgr = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_QMGR_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_QMGR_ENT_EE);

                qr = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_QR_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_QR_ENT_EE);

                ql = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_QL_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_QL_ENT_EE);

                codigo = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_CODIGO_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_CODIGO_ENT_EE);

                mensaje2 = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_MENSAJE_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_MENSAJE_ENT_EE);
                mensaje2 = mensaje2.trim();

                timeout = comando.substring(Constantes.S_IND_TIMEOUT_ENT_EE, Constantes.E_IND_TIMEOUT_ENT_EE);

                dest = func.obtenerPorKey(destinos, Constantes.KEY_COLA_REQ + codigo); //Obteniendo par de colas necesarias!!

                if(dest == null)
                    throw new Exception(Constantes.DEST_ERROR);

                salida = manager.accessQueue(dest.getQueue(), MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT); //Seteando cola de response!!


                mensaje.writeBytes(mensaje2);
                mensaje.messageId = mensajeHost.getKeyString().getBytes();
                mensaje.correlationId = mensajeHost.getKeyString().getBytes();


                mensaje.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;

                salida.put(mensaje);



                salida.close();
                manager.disconnect();

            }
```

I close the connection to the queue at the end of each invoke of the timer, but seems that too many channel connections are opened and then it overloads it. So, I wanted to know how can I do to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your try/catch logic?  Your disconnect() is correct but either the put() or closr() is throwing an exception and your disconnect() is not being executed.

Comment: I didn't put it in the code because is too long, but there's actually a try/catch that prints in a log on exception, and that's not happening.

Comment: Put your disconnect() in finally.